# Unpacking JavaScript (p,a,c,k,e,d) Function

Tags: javascript, c#, uwp

I have a UWP app and I use `HtmlAgilityPack` to parse some web pages and show information in the app. Now I have come across a page where I need to execute a function to get the next link for the document.
I ran the specific code in a blank `UWP JavaScript` app and was able to see the link. But I have no idea as how I can run the function in `C#`. Since it is a different language, do I need to create my own set of function to get information from the data or do I have to link any JavaScript library (if it's possible) to perform the action?

This is the `function` that I get from the page, in order to be able to navigate further I need to run it and get the `string` generated from it.

```
eval(function (p, a, c, k, e, d)
{
while (c--)
    if (k[c])
        p = p.replace(new RegExp('\\b' + c.toString(a) + '\\b', 'g'), k[c]);
return p
} ('3("3a").39({38:"6://5.1c.1b.1a:19/37/v.36",35:"6://5.1c.1b.1a:19/i/34/33/15.32",31:"",30:"2z",2y:"2x",2w:2v,2u:"8",2t:"2s",2r:[],2q:{2p:\'#2o\',2n:22,2m:"2l",2k:0}});b f;b k=0;b 7=0;3().2j(2(x){a(7>0)k+=x.18-7;7=x.18;a(0!=0&&k>=0){7=-1;3().2i();3().2h(2g);$(\'#2f\').j();$(\'h.g\').j()}});3().2e(2(x){7=-1});3().2d(2(x){17(x)});3().2c(2(){$(\'h.g\').j()});2 17(x){$(\'h.g\').2b();a(f)2a;f=1;$.29(\'6://12.9/16-28/27.16?26=25&24=15&23=21-20-1z-1y-1x\',2(14){$(\'#1w\').1v(14)})};3().1u(\'1t\',2(){b 13=3().1s();13.1r(\'1q\',2(){11.10(\'z-y\')[0].w[1].1p="6://12.9";11.10(\'z-y\')[0].w[1].1o="<u>1n - 1m 1l 1k & 1j</u>"});a($.c(\'4\')=="d"){t.s("6://r.q.p/o/8.n","m 9 1i",e,"l")}1h{t.s("6://r.q.p/o/d.n","m 9 1g",e,"l")}});2 e(){$.c(\'4\')==\'8\'?4=\'d\':4=\'8\';$.c(\'4\',4);1f.1e.1d()};', 36, 119, '||function|jwplayer|primaryCookie||http|p09821659|html5|to|if|var|cookie|flash|switchMode|vvplay|video_ad|div||show|tt9821659|button2|Switch|png|images|tv|flashx|static|addButton|this|center||childNodes||featured|jw|getElementsByClassName|document|streamin|container|data|sgqbf1k6kqfh|cgi|doPlay|position|8777|106|81|79|reload|location|window|Flash|else|HTML5|Storage|Sharing|Video|Free|Streamin|innerHTML|href|contextmenu|addEventListener|getContainer|ready|on|html|fviews|3a8183ea9a69ef9630b94e14f10dd735|1484917924|186|182|9821659||hash|file_code|view|op|index_dl|bin|get|return|hide|onComplete|onPlay|onSeek|play_limit_box|false|setFullscreen|stop|onTime|backgroundOpacity|Arial|fontFamily|fontSize|FFFFFF|color|captions|tracks|start|startparam|primary|326|height|580|width|2567|duration|skin|jpg|01964|01|image|mp4|tcipboyrkduzcg3h5gtcldvuyiloqwnoa5padad4cgy4d5wmp77locnp4ypa|file|setup|vplayer'.split('|')))
```

So is it possible to achieve it in C#? If yes, then how do I do that?
Thanks.

[**Edit**]
I found [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/csharp/comments/3duzus/cwindows_phonehow_can_i_decode_packed_javascript/) while searching for a way to do it. It is quite similar but still need a few tweaks to accomplish. I understand some part of it but the `Regex` part is way out of my way.
Does anyone else know if it can be adapted to my situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/csharp/comments/3duzus/cwindows_phonehow_can_i_decode_packed_javascript/) (also mentioned above) nice article on how to do it. Someone made this `Regex` in C# to solve their own problem. I am happy to say it helped me so I am going to put it up here in case someone needs it in future.

```
string inputHtml = @"the function you get from scraping the page";
string[] data = Regex.Match(inputHtml, "'([a-zA-Z0-9_|]{30,})'").Groups[1].Value.Split('|');
```

The above code snippet will provide you with an array of different strings and you can look through them for whatever information you need to get.
I also made some progress on 2 websites and I am going to share the code that I used so it may help someone else in future.

I am working with following code snippet in my app to get the video link from **"estream.to"** and **"streamin.to"**.

```
if (videoLink.Host == "estream.to")
{
   IEnumerable<HtmlNode> links = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("script").Where(l => l.Attributes.Contains("type") && (l.InnerText.Contains("mp4") || l.InnerText.Contains("m3u8")) && l.InnerText.Contains("(p,a,c,k,e,d)"));
    foreach (var link in links)
    {
       value = link.InnerText;
       if (value.Contains("mp4"))
       {
          value = link.InnerText;
          break;
       }
    }
    string[] data = Regex.Match(value, "'([a-zA-Z0-9_|]{30,})'").Groups[1].Value.Split('|');
    if (data.Count() > 20)
    {
       value = string.Format("https://{0}.{1}.{2}/hls/{3}/index-v1-a1.m3u8", data[10], data[4], data[3], data[17]);
    }


    }
    else if (videoLink.Host == "streamin.to")
    {
         IEnumerable<HtmlNode> links = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("script").Where(l => l.Attributes.Contains("type") && (l.InnerText.Contains("mp4") || l.InnerText.Contains("m3u8")) && l.InnerText.Contains("(p,a,c,k,e,d)"));
    foreach (var link in links)
    {
       value = link.InnerText;
       if (value.Contains("mp4"))
       {
           value = link.InnerText;
           break;
       }
    }
    string[] data = Regex.Match(value, "'([a-zA-Z0-9_|]{30,})'").Groups[1].Value.Split('|');
    if (data.Count() > 20)
    {
        List<int> ip = new List<int>();
        for (int x = 41; x <= 50; x++)
        {
           //check ip
           int val = 0;
           int.TryParse(data[x], out val);
           if (val != 0)
           {
              ip.Add(val);
           }
        }
        if (ip.Count > 0)
        {
           int[] ipValue = ip.ToArray();
           string secondParam = "";
           for (int x = 0; x < data.Count(); x++)
           {
               // string length is more than 50
               if (data[x].Length > 50)
               {
                  secondParam = data[x];
               }
           }
  // Edit: I have come across a problem with this so I am updating the answer.
           if (ipValue.Count() == 4)
           {
              value = string.Format("http://5.{0}.{1}.{2}:{3}/{4}/v.mp4", ipValue[3], ipValue[2], ipValue[1], ipValue[0], secondParam);
           }
           else if (ipValue.Count() == 5)
           {
              value = string.Format("http://{0}.{1}.{2}.{3}:{4}/{5}/v.mp4", ipValue[4], ipValue[3], ipValue[2], ipValue[1], ipValue[0], secondParam);
           }
           else
           {
              // this is where the problem occurs 
           }
        }
    }
```

Hope it helps anyone :). Thanks to the person who made it possible.

**Update:**
I found out that "streamin.to" uses different algorithms in different places. So far I think there are 3 types of codes.

1. IP starts from "5.x.x.x:x" and last 4 parts are available in the code but the 5 has to be put by you.
2. IP starts differently but all the parts of IP are available in the code so there is nothing to worry about here.
3. IP starts differently again but only 3 parts of IP are available from all the 5. From what I experienced I got "x.92.x.211:8777" since there were 2 places unknown it was a wrong `Uri` and in the whole code there was no other information on how to get those missing.

Hopefully, this could be some issue with the piece of code that I am using. Maybe playing with it could shed some light on it.